# Error: No suitable device found: no active connection or device

Tags: network-manager, vpn, network-bridge

I am trying to SSH to a machine and initiate a VPN, created whilst in front of the machine through GNOME (Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS);

```
$ nmcli con 
NAME                      UUID                                   TYPE              SCOPE    TIMESTAMP-REAL                    
Auto eth0                 ebd17105-b46d-4405-893e-4da47c592861   802-3-ethernet    system   never                             
br0                       3f94195e-bece-45a4-af6f-400879063ea6   802-3-ethernet    system   never                             
NAME                      UUID                                   TYPE              SCOPE    TIMESTAMP-REAL                    
testvpn                    0da910b2-e094-43ed-8c12-fd078fe7d52a   vpn               user     Tue 12 Jul 2011 22:52:39 BST      
myvpn                   c6157e94-3713-498d-a9a7-35eb1aae40ab   vpn               user     Mon 11 Jul 2011 22:01:16 BST

$ nmcli con up id myvpn
Error: No suitable device found: no active connection or device.
```

I have been searching the Internet but can't find any answers. I think it must be something to do with the fact that eth0 is a member of bridge br0 (I run KVM machines), and I get the same error on another machine which again, has eth0 in br0, for use with KVM.

Do I need to tell nmcli perhaps that br0 is active?

Comment: here is a bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager-applet/+bug/1013963 As a workaround it would be possible to create the vpn connection from a virtual machine.

Comment: I see, yes this is my problem. I will have to deal with it for now, thank you for pointing this out though. Good to see it has been acknowledged.